# Exec imagemagick convert via C#

Tags: c#, imagemagick

When I open a command window in windows and use the imagemagick convert command:

convert /somedir/Garden.jpg /somedir/Garden.png

It works as expected.

What I am trying to do is executing the same command as above using C#.

I tried using  System.Diagnostics.Process, however, no foo.png gets created.

I am using this code:

```
      var proc = new Process
      {
          StartInfo =
          {
              Arguments = string.Format("{0}Garden.jpg {1}Garden.png",
              TEST_FILE_DIR,
              TEST_FILE_DIR),
              FileName = @"C:\xampp\ImageMagick-6.5.4-Q16\convert",
              UseShellExecute = false,
              CreateNoWindow = true,
              RedirectStandardOutput = false,
              RedirectStandardError = false
          }
      };

      proc.Start();
```

No exception gets thrown, but no .png is written, either.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My guess is that `TEST_FILE_DIR` contains a space - so you have to quote it.

Try this:

```
Arguments = string.Format("\"{0}Garden.jpg\" \"{1}Garden.png\"",
                          TEST_FILE_DIR,
                          TEST_FILE_DIR)
```

You might also want to give the filename including the extension, e.g.

```
FileName = @"C:\xampp\ImageMagick-6.5.4-Q16\convert.exe"
```

Comment: That worked, thank you! You just put quotes around the arguments, right?

Comment: Yup - just to cope with spaces.